# How to prove that the matrix is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

$A$ and $B$ are $3\times 3$ matrices ($A,B \in \mathcal{M}_{3 \times 3}(\mathbb{R})$). There are two equations:

$$A^2+3BA=I$$

$$A^2=AB$$

**I want to prove that $A$ does not have an inverse.**

I tried to substitute $AB$ at the first equation but could not get the solution.
I know that if the matrix is invertible, then $AA^{-1}=I$.

Comment: Your first equation says that $(A+3B)A=I$. What does this tell you about whether or not $A$ is invertible?

Comment: $A$ has an inverse.

Comment: By the way, matrix $AB$ and matrix $BA$ are different. So you can't substitute $A^2 = AB$ into the first equation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first equation says :

$$(A+3B)A=I$$

Taking determinant both the sides, you get

$$\det(A+3B) \cdot \det (A)=1$$

This implies $\det (A)$ can never be $0$, hence $A$ ***is*** invertible.

Moreover, you can easily see that the inverse of $A$ is $A+3B$, since both multiply to identity matrix.

Comment: Yes, but potentially the second equation $A^2=AB$ could give a contradiction then.

Comment: @DietrichBurde if both the equation are simultaneously satisfied by $A$ , then $\det A \neq 0$. However we can conclude that $\det A=\det B$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, nothing wrong. I just wanted to say, if you have two equations, i.e., $AB=I$ and $AB=0$, then you can conclude from $AB=I$ that $A$ is invertible - but there is no such $A$, because of $AB=0$. So $A$ is not invertible, and invertible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That's not the situation here, here we have 2 values $\det(A)$ and two equations. One of the equations is satisfied by both the values of $\det(A)$ and other is satisfied by only one. Hence, we can conclude that $\det(A)$ has only one value, and that too, which is common root of both the equations.hence we can conclude that $A$ is definitely invertible.

Comment: @DietrichBurde The second equation just yields $B=A$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde It is not proven here whether there exists any pair of $A$ and $B$ that satisfies these equations; for proof that there is, see your own answer. But if there is, then such $A$ and $B$ must satisfy
$$(A+3B)A = I,$$
so the left inverse of any such $A$, hence also its right inverse, is $A+3B$. Which means $A$ do have an inverse.

Comment: @peterwhy That means I am correct, right?

Comment: @JaideepKhare right, I agree with your answer. Though that determinant consideration is not necessary.

Comment: @peterwhy Yes, it isn't necessary. BTW, that was my approach then to solve this question.

Comment: Thanks alot, you guys made it clear for me.

Answer (score 6):

Take $A=B=\frac{1}{2}I$, with $I=I_3$ the identity matrix. Then we have
$$
A^2+3BA=(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{3}{4})I=I, 
$$
and also $A^2=AB$. However, both $A$ and $B$ are invertible.